# gnuplot - plot random points inside an ellipsoid

Tags: math, random, geometry, gnuplot, ellipse

I want to create and plot a set of random points within the boundaries of an ellipsoid using gnuplot. Is it possible to do this directly in gnuplot, or would I need to generate my random data points in an external program?

Ultimately I would like to produce an ellipsoid figure similar to this [ellipse figure](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/ellipse.html).

There are some examples on the use of [rand](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/random.html) and [cylindrical/spherical coordinates](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/world.html), but I'm not sure how to generate the random points inside the boundaries of an ellipsoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on @Bernhard's answer, here is how you can do that with gnuplot only. To reuse a random number, you can put the two `rand` calls and the assignments to variables in the first argument of the `using` statement, separated by commas. The `using` statements are evaluated from left to right, so you can access those variables in all following `using` parameters.

To demonstrate this, see the following examples:

```
set samples 1000
plot '+' using (x=rand(0), y=rand(0), x):(y)
```

Applying this to the ellipsoid, this gives the script:

```
a=3
b=2
phi=30*pi/180

max(x,y) = (x > y ? x : y)
set xrange[-max(a,b):max(a,b)]
set yrange[-max(a,b):max(a,b)]

set offset 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1
set samples 2000

ex(x, y) = a*(2*x-1)
ey(x, y) = b*(sqrt(1-((2*x-1))**2))*(2*y-1)

unset key    
plot '+' using (x=rand(0), y=rand(0), ex(x,y)*cos(phi)-ey(x,y)*sin(phi)):\
               (ey(x,y)*cos(phi)+ex(x,y)*sin(phi)) pt 7 ps 0.5
```

with the result:

[image]

This, however, leads to an apparently unequal distribution of the points (see the agglomarations at the ellipse's ends, see @andyras's comment). To avoid this, here is how you can filter equally distributed random points to be inside the ellipsoid:

```
a=3
b=2
set angles degree
phi=30

max(x,y) = (x > y ? x : y)
set xrange[-max(a,b):max(a,b)]
set yrange[-max(a,b):max(a,b)]

set offset 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1
set samples 2000
set size ratio 1

check(x, y) = (((x/a)**2 + (y/b)**2) <= 1)
unset key
plot '+' using (x=2*a*(rand(0)-0.5), y=2*b*(rand(0)-0.5), \
     check(x,y) ? x*cos(phi)-y*sin(phi) : 1/0):\
     (x*sin(phi)+y*cos(phi)) pt 7 ps 0.5
```

This gives the much better result:

[image]

Extending this to three dimensions:

```
a=3
b=1
c=1
set angles degree
phi=30

mx(x,y) = (x > y ? x : y)
max(x,y,z) = mx(mx(x,y), mx(x,z))
set xrange[-max(a,b,c):max(a,b,c)]
set yrange[-max(a,b,c):max(a,b,c)]
set zrange[-max(a,b,c):max(a,b,c)]

set offset 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1
set samples 2000
set size ratio 1

set ticslevel 0
set view 60, 330

check(x, y, z) = (((x/a)**2 + (y/b)**2 + (z/c)**2) <= 1)
unset key
splot '+' using (x = 2*a*(rand(0)-0.5), \
                 y = 2*b*(rand(0)-0.5), \
                 z=2*c*(rand(0)-0.5), \
                 check(x,y,z) ? x*cos(phi)-y*sin(phi) : 1/0):\
                 (x*sin(phi)+y*cos(phi)):(z) pt 7 ps 0.5
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: Wow, I did not know you could create variables inside the `using` part!

Comment: @Bernhard The first time I'd seen this was in the [running average demo](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/running_avg.html). See e.g. my answers to [How do I create a 3d phase-space plot in gnuplot?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17945044/2604213), [gnuplot matrix or palette using one line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18297966/2604213), and [Plotting different columns on the same file using boxes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18239919/2604213) for some, well, let's call them "use cases" ;).

Comment: In some case I'd like the inline `awk` processing, but some of the examples you show are really powerfull. Learned something today! :D

Comment: @Bernhard I do also prefer using external tools for preprocessing. But for some simple cases, or when you cannot rely on external tools being available it can be nice. Although it gets very fast very confusing.

Comment: I seem to notice more points at the ends of the ellipse, and I am wondering if the points are not randomly distributed because the rand function is used to give cartesian points which are then transformed into the ellipse.  It might give a more random distribution to generate random (x,y) pairs and then filter them to be within the bounds of an ellipse (if this matters).

Comment: @andyras Good point! See my updated answer. This look much better.

Comment: I finally have time to look at this. Thank you to both of you for providing answers. I will probably vote for this answer as the correct one, since it works across platforms. Could one avoid the non-random/unequal distribution of points within the ellipsoid by using spherical coordinates (polar coordinates for the ellipse)? Oh, and I thought *I* knew a lot about gnuplot...

Comment: @tommy.carstensen I think the second solution has equally distributed points.

Comment: @Cristoph It does. Thanks. I'm having difficulty extending this to an ellipsoid, but I haven't given up yet.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen See my edit for a 3D-version. Haven't included rotation in the third dimension.

Comment: @Cristoph you are the king of gnuplot. I wish you hadn't given me the solution. I almost had it solved, but thanks anyway. I have to find an explanation/derivation for this coordinate transformation somewhere online: x*cos(phi)-y*sin(phi):(x*sin(phi)+y*cos(phi)):(z) THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a method to reuse the `rand(0)` in the parametric plot example that you showed, but with an internal call to command line tools, you can do that with some modifications:

```
unset key
a=3
b=2

set xrange [-a:a]
set yrange [-b:b]
set style function dots
plot "<seq 1000 | awk '{print rand(), rand()}'" using (a*(2*$1-1)):(b*(sqrt(1-((2*$1-1))**2))*(2*$2-1))
```

To convert this to 3D is left as an exercise to the reader (just continue on these expressions)