# Moving Standard Deviation Gnuplot

Tags: python, statistics, gnuplot, standard-deviation

is there a way of ploting a moving standard deviation in gnuplot?

I have a large file from which I am plotting my regular signal. Now I would need to calculate/plot the standard devation for y based on a frame from x.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**Added description:**

That is how my data is set up:

I plot using this command: 
`plot "Data.csv" using 1:3 title 'Sample' ls 1`

Data File looks like this

```
#Value1;Value2;Time
0.1;0.2;1
0.11;0.2;1.5
0.12;0.3;1.9
0.11;0.2;2.1
0.3;0.21;2.2
0.2;0.31;2.9
```

The time series is irregular. To calculate the standard dev I need to take into account a fixed frame that is time depended. In this example I would use a time frame of `1`. So for the value at time `1.9` I would need to take all values into account between `1.4`to `2.4`.

Comment: My tentative answer is 'yes,' but before I post anything I would like a little more detail.  Would you like to compute the stdev of a set number of points, say 2 in each direction from a certain time point?

Comment: I have a time series with values. Now I would like to plot the stdev based on the specific time frame. (e.g. time frame has a range of 5 day into the future and the past)

Comment: It not impossible, see e.g. the [running average demo](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/running_avg.html) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17945044/2604213) about how to access data from a previous row. But it is very unflexible (when changing the number of points), and is very cumbersome. I would suggest you to use an external script, e.g. using `python`, to do this computation. This can be done on-the-fly with e.g. `plot '< python mov_stdvar.py'`.

Comment: Could you give a short example?

Comment: That depends on the format of you actual input data, especially, because it involves time data, which needs to be read in properly. Can you include a short sample of your input data? Should the `x`-range be given in number of points or a time span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Christoph that python makes this much easier.  Here is an example of how to compute the running stdev in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Computes a moving standard deviation for a data file')
parser.add_argument('--number', '-n', help='Window size (number of points to either side)', type=int)
parser.add_argument('dataFile', help='Name of data file', type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()
n = args.number

# I hope you have numpy, it makes things much easier
import numpy as np

# assuming two-column time/datum format
data = np.loadtxt(args.dataFile)

for ii in range(n,len(data)-n):
    print data[ii,0], np.std(data[ii-n:ii+n+1,1])
```

Now you can call the script on the data file from gnuplot:

```
plot '<python boxcarStdev.py -n 5 mydata.dat'
```

Comment: Should it be `plot '<python boxcarStdev.py -n 5 mydata.dat'`?

Comment: Gnuplot does not plot the second value of the python script when I call it with the line I wrote above. When I run the python script alone it produces a nice output stream of my data (e.g. `71.5261680406 -0.67`).However Gnuplot seems to ignore  the second value when plotting. Any advice?

Comment: When you use that plot command, you don't need to change the datafile separator (maybe you have a `set datafile separator ';'` from plotting the raw `csv`-file). Buts thats only a guess, as we can't know how your plotting script looks like. Also, taking your sample data you need to use `np.loadtxt(args.dataFile, delimiter=';')` and for the output you must use `print data[ii,2]...` (time is the third column, if the comments in your sample file are correct).

Comment: Thanks, for the comment. I had the `set datafile separator ";"` in the gnuplot script.